# Conditionally choose Namespace for instantiation

Tags: c#, dynamic, namespaces

i have two Namespaces with the same classes (different versions of the dll).

```
var dynamically = new NamespaceA.Classname();
```

how choose conditionally NamespaceA.Classname() or NamespaceB.Classname() at runtime without 'dynamic'?

Answer (score 0):

Both your classes have to be somehow (sensibly) compatibe with each other, either by inheriting from a common base class or implementing an common interface. Think `IDbConnection` and various implementations thereof.